# glassfish: Authorization has been refused for credentials [user: admin] given in this request

Tags: server, java, password, administration, glassfish

On Ubuntu 14.04 Tahr and Glassfish 4.1, I managed to reset my glassfish master password as so:

```
ejb@ix:~$
ejb@ix:~$ glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin change-master-password
Enter the current master password>
Enter the new master password>
Enter the new master password again>
Command change-master-password executed successfully.
ejb@ix:~$
ejb@ix:~$ glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin change-admin-password
Enter admin user name [default: admin]>admin
Enter the admin password>
Enter the new admin password>
Enter the new admin password again>
Authorization has been refused for credentials [user: admin] given in this request.
(Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
Command change-admin-password failed.
ejb@ix:~$
ejb@ix:~$ glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin change-admin-password
Enter admin user name [default: admin]>admin
Enter the admin password>
Enter the new admin password>
Enter the new admin password again>
Authorization has been refused for credentials [user: admin] given in this request.
(Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
Command change-admin-password failed.
ejb@ix:~$
ejb@ix:~$
```

how do I reset the admin password?  I tried "adminadmin" for the, apparently, default admin password -- but that didn't work for me.  (For anyone passing by, the default master password is "changeit".)

note:  in order to use glassfish 4.x, I downloaded directly from the website and unzipped the file, so this is **not** from a repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the doc, see 1st page of Chapter 1 of the [Administration Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf)

> Note: For the zip bundle of GlassFish Server 4.0, **the default
>   administrator login is admin, with no password**, which means that no
>   login is required.